# How to develop regarding lookup on custom aspx page?

Tags: dynamics-crm

How to develop regrading lookup on custom page where we are updating the existing task. This page looks same as MS CRM task page. Now here how to get the regarding and owner lookups on custom aspx page? How to develop the Notes tab on custom page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SDK that is available for free with CRM, and you cannot reuse the CRM stuff, because it's not supported. But if you want to replicate the exact same behavior, there is a couple of solutions out there. Take a look at http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/filtered-lookup-crm-4/